# Methods in a Runnable class block when sleep is called in the run method?

Tags: java, thread-safety, queue, runnable

I have a class that implements Runnable interface: something like:

```
    public class MyClass implements Runnable{

            public MyClass(){
            //I have a queue object
            mQueue = new LinkedList<MyObject>();

            }

            public void addToQueue(MyObject onj){
               mQueue.add(obj);
            }

            @Override
            public void run(){
               while(true)
               {
                     //Do some stuff(dequeue and write to file)
                     Thread.sleep(500);

               }
            }
         }
}
```

So this runnabale class will be started in another class. the class that adds to this Queue (which also has started the Runnable) will always add to the queue.

I want to know when the sleep is called in the while loop, does the method `addToQueue` still work? I mean the class which started this thread can add to the queue when this thread is in sleep...so basically is the `run()` method blocks other methods in the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Classes* and *threads* are independent concepts.  Classes and methods do not block; threads do.

If you have this:

```
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    mc.run();   // this will never return
```

This code runs in a single thread; the `Thread.sleep(500)` runs in the thread and blocks the thread with each call.  While the thread is sleeping, execution in the thread is halted.  (In fact, `mc.run()` will never return due to its endless loop.)

However, if more than one thread has a reference to a particular `MyClass` instance, then each thread can independently make calls to methods on the object.  Each thread executes independently of others (except when *synchronization* is involved).

```
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();
    Thread thread = new Thread(mc);
    thread.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();
        mc.addToQueue(obj);
    }
```

This code creates a new thread (call it **thread B**) and starts it, which causes `run()` to be executed in the new thread, on the `mc` object instance.  Now there are two threads -- the original one, **thread A**, and the new one, **thread B**.  Both execute independently of each other.  In particular, **thread A** can manipulate the object at (for our purposes here) the same time **thread B** is running `run()`.  If you are not careful to avoid potentially conflicting manipulations, you will experience unexpected results and difficult-to-reproduce failures.  In your code, if more than one thread can call `addToQueue()` on a given object without adequate synchronization, then you will eventually encounter trouble because `LinkedList` is not a thread-safe class.

Concurrency and thread safety can be challenging to get correct.  The book *Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz, et. al. is an excellent start.

Answer (score 1):

Try it, but sure, it should still work just fine as long as your call this in a thread different from the that of the code that is calling the method. Also that while true code shouldn't call a synchronized bit of code that would lock use of your method of interest.

Comment: I dont have access to my own PC...I was thinking about problems of my code on the fly. I will check but I wanted to hear a rock solid yes or no :D

Comment: You should always test before asking.

Comment: @Sean87: but there are no absolutes. There will be conditions where the method won't run, where your code is locked.

Comment: what kind of conditions, maybe having a synchronized statement in the while loop?